# How to make flash file not downloadable?

Tags: php, html, flash

I want that my flash file on my website, can't be downloaded by anyone.
Is there any way that i can do that?
As Firefox and many browser has many add-ones which easily detect out flash content and after they can download the flash file?

Comment: If one can't download the flash file then how can the browser display it?

Comment: As others have said, there's no point in having flash file that is not downloadable. Though, you may think about making it unusable from anywhere but your web site.

Comment: ok..i thought of giving any protection to my videos...bcz i want that only premium user can see the videos...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: No.

Remember that in order to display the contents of the flash file, it will have to be downloaded to the client in any case, and is usually saved to a temporary file on disk. There's really no way from keeping a browser from saving the files you send it to disk, short of not sending the files in the first place. (In which case, well, the flash cannot be displayed, because the client doesn't have it.)

Answer (score 1):

And what exactly is the use of a Flash file that you can't download? If it can't be downloaded then you won't be able to view it in a browser. So don't put it online, then nobody will be able to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

But you can make it harder for someone to download and reuse the file.

You should look into serving the flash file via a PHP script so that it can do checks before serving the file. And in the flash file you can do checks like what the page address is before running the code, etc.